# How to print the value of a custom control in the Customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

To the Customizer section of my WordPress admin area, I have added a custom setting and custom control.  I would like to now print the value of this control.  How can I do this?  The code used to add the custom setting/control is below (from the [WordPress customize_register() page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register)):

```
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'test_setting', array(
            'default'        => 'value_xyz',
            'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
            'type'           => 'option',
        ));
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'test_control', array(
            'label'      => __('Text Test', 'themename'),
            'section'    =>  'spacious_slider_number_section1',
            'settings'   => 'test_setting',
        ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');
```

The text input field displays as expected in the Customizer ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mnQj.jpg)).  I would like to now echo the value of this text input field When my page's PHP template is loaded.  But when I try to do so, a blank value is returned.  The code I used to do so, added to my page's PHP template, is below:

echo get_theme_mod('test_setting');

Furthermore, the type seems to be boolean (instead of string, as I would expect), i.e. `gettype(get_theme_mod('test_setting');` returns `boolean`.

Finally, If I print the value of `get_theme_mods()`, my custom setting/control does not appear in the array.

Comment: Your code is good except in add_setting.You have assigned option for type parameter. It will save separate option for each field. If you use  'type' => 'theme_mod' it will solve your problem.

Comment: please try this : $test = get_theme_mod( 'test_setting' ); 
echo $test;

Comment: What was mentioned above about using theme_mod instead of option is correct. However, you should also ALWAYS use the 2nd argument in the get_theme_mod function, otherwise it will return false (bool) if the value has not been saved in the customizer. You need to use theme-mods and also define the 2nd argument in get_theme_mod which is the default value that should be used as a fallback when the theme_mod is not saved in the db.

Comment: @Aristeides Thanks.  I had been omitting it, but I now see that it is very helpful with troubleshooting, especially when the eventual control I insert will be a checkbox, which takes Boolean values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is perfect just need to change `'theme_mod'` instead of `'option'` it will solve this.

```
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'test_setting', array(
            'default'        => 'value_xyz',
            'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
            'type'           => 'theme_mod',
        ));
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'test_control', array(
            'label'      => __('Text Test', 'themename'),
            'section'    =>  'spacious_slider_number_section1',
            'settings'   => 'test_setting',
        ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');
```

And to retrieve it

```
get_theme_mod( 'test_setting' );
```

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: If `type` is set to `option` then you can get the value with `get_option()`.

Comment: @Tejas thanks, it worked.  Just so I learn more about my problem and the fix, is there official documentation about the 'type' parameter in this case?  This page doesn't say much about it:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/